# Unable to Connect HP Pavilion dv6700 Laptop to TV Using VGA-to-HDMI Cable

Tags: hdmi, connection, vga, tv

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I am currently experiencing an issue with my **HP Pavilion dv6700** laptop running a 64-bit version of **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy)**. **I am attempting to connect my laptop to my television for use as an external monitor.** However, I am having some difficulty getting it to work.

My laptop possesses only a VGA port for external monitor connection, while my television only has HDMI inputs available. To bridge this gap, I have been trying to use a VGA to HDMI cable. From the 'Displays' option in the settings menu, I've explored and tried every conceivable configuration. Despite this, I have been unable to successfully get a video output to appear on my TV.

I have checked the cable's connection and it seems to be fine. Moreover, I have also tried switching to different HDMI inputs on the TV but to no avail.

I am unsure as to what steps I should take next to resolve this issue and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. **Are there any specific drivers or software that can aid in resolving this problem?**

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best regards,
Baji

Comment: Are you sure you have the right cable? Most VGA - HDMI Cables are one-way, usually being HDMI to the PC and VGA to the Monitor. Adapters that go from VGA to PC and HDMI to Monitor will usually have a USB cable for extra power and a 3.5mm Jack for Audio from the PC to HDMI, like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B072KR7MJW/), make sure you have the right cable, might be worth testing it with another device if you can.

Comment: You mention 64-bit 22.04; the only architecture where 32 & 64 bit is available is for ARM processors; so you're using ARM64?  (64-bit is unclear given amd64, arm64, ppc64el, riscv64... exist). You don't mention if Server or Desktop ((they have different kernel stack defaults, which changes kernel modules or what are commonly called *drivers*) so being specific can help (*I'm not sure this will help though*). I suspect it's cable issue (*cable connectors isn't the only requirement for it to work; was the cable wiring intended for your use-case; VGA=analog by design, HDMI=digital*)